# PyInstaller executable does nothing

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyinstaller

Have installed **pyinstaller** on Ubuntu (21.04) platform, then used it to generate an executable (per terminal commands below) from a .py script -- a simple "Hello" type program:
`print("hello")`
When I run the executable file nothing happens -- trying to determine if I have missed a step.

```
installing:
    pip3 install pyinstaller
    pip3 show pyinstaller ==> Name: pyinstaller  Version: 4.6
invoking:
    pyinstaller /home/kdt/PythonK/simple1.py
creates:
    /home/kdt/simple1.spec  file
    /home/kdt/build/simple1 folder with objects
    /home/kdt/dist/simple1  folder with objects
    /home/kdt/dist/simple1/simple1  executable
```

Comment: Can you show us the script you're running, and how you're running it?

Comment: It could have been problem with your script to package. It's hard to determine at this point. And your script might be too complicated to share too. My suggestion would be to use the same step to package a simple "Hello World" type of script with pyinstaller. See what it got you. Then you may update this question with what you found. At that point, the new strip down script can be your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem.

Comment: The .py script is simply that:
    print ("hello")

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to run it from the File explorer by right-clicking on it and selecting Run. By executing it from the Terminal instead I get the desired output.